# how to manage image file in c# for asp.net mvc web-application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to manage user picture in c# for my web application

i want all images  as

1.png  2.png 3.png if user upload GIF and jpeg that it is convert to .png

how i can do this.

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you want to do. How are the users uploading images? Where are you storing them? Have you even tried solving the problem and what issues did you encounter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=image+upload+asp.net+mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phil Haack just wrote about [Uploading a file (or files) with ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+haacked+%28you%27ve+been+HAACKED%29).

This will give you a good starting place with your image upload requirements.

Once you've obtained the image from the user you can name it anything you like before saving. You could store all images together and link the user to the image via a database entry or you could create a user image folder and store the image in there.

There's a huge variety of ways you can accomplish your goal so these are just a couple of sugestions to help you along the way.